# ListView layout_width match_parent and fill_parent not working inside of TableRow

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using `TableLayout` and Some `TableRow` elements has `ListView` inside. Until I load data in `ListView` All Items in `TableRow` works fine. As Data has been loaded in `ListViews` `layout_width` `match_parent` and `fill_parent` stops working.

Note: In this Question I am asking about `layout_width` issue. My `layout_height` is working great and also I don't have `scrolling` issue.

Following is the XML of my Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_lbl_topSongs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/app_orange"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_lbl_topSongs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top Songs"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/app_white" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_content_topSongs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_topSongs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_viewMore_topSongs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/app_offwhite"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_viewMore_topSongs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="View More"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/app_gray" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_lbl_topVideos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/app_orange"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_lbl_topVideos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top Videos"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/app_white" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_content_topVideos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_topVideos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_viewMore_topVideos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/app_offwhite"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_viewMore_topVideos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="View More"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/app_gray" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_lbl_topRingtones"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/app_orange"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_lbl_topRingtones"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top Ringtones"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/app_white" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_content_topRingtones"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_topRingtones"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_viewMore_topRingtones"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/app_offwhite"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_viewMore_topRingtones"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="View More"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/app_gray" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Update:

I have managed to use ListView inside of ScrollView with following codes.
I registered TouchListner

```
lv_topSongs = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_topSongs);
lv_topSongs.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

My TouchListner in which I am passing touch event to ScrollView and Disabling Touch Even on ListView.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    mScrollView.onTouchEvent(event);
    return false;
}
```

I am setting height after loading data in ListView With following Code.

`setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lv_topSongs);`

And My `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren` function

```
/**** Method for Setting the Height of the ListView dynamically.
     **** Hack to fix the issue of not showing all the items of the ListView
     **** when placed inside a ScrollView  ****/
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

    }
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: You can't use ListView inside ScrollView.

Comment: @Haresh I am disabling `onTouch` events on My `ListViews` and passing those events to `ScroolView`. I have no scrolling or Height issues of my `ListViews`. I have issue of width in  my `ListViews`. Please check updated question. It has screenshot as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this Problem by Assigning weight to `ListView` `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Still unable to understand why I have to assign weight even there is only one Item in `TableRow` however This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your list to fill the height equal to your table row you will have to give some fixed height to your table row..
Try it.